# If components X and Y use shared data, what is the most maintainable way to do that?

Tags: angular

If components X and Y are children of component A, and X and Y use some shared data that comes from a REST api call, what is the best way/pattern to do it?

Since the data from the api call doesn't change often, we only need to access the api once for both components.

### Option 1: Both components use a Service

### Option 2: Component A uses a Service, and passes the data into the children

---

What if component X or Y is more than one level separated from component A? Do we just pass the data all the way down? Even if the intermediate component doesn't use it?

Comment: I think the question is too general to find objective answers to. There must be some circumnstance that helps you and us to take a side.

Answer (score 0):

Go for option 2, that way you have compartmentalization for debugging and get a more extendable/maintainable software. I wouldn't mind about "passing the data" along the component hierarchy (unless is a heavy burden), on the bright side it gives you an extra layer of security.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in a separate file only containing you data.

```
 app/hero.ts
 export class Hero {
   id: number;
   name: string;
 }
```

Component A will use the service and store data in Hero class. Import this component in X and Y component.